# Probability calculus

Tags: probability

There are 21 cubic dice in a box: 14 of them are regular, and 7 are false, with sixes on all sides. We repeat the following experiment 4 times: we draw a die (with replacement) and roll it once. Calculate the probability that sixes will be the outcomes of all the rolls.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find the chance you get a six on the first roll?

Comment: P(four times 6) = P(four times 6, four times regular dice) + P(four times 6, three times regular dice, one false dice) + ... - now the question is if these drawings and rollings are independent, if so, use Binomal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the events are with replacement, they are independent, so we can simply find the probability of rolling a six once, and raise it to the fourth power.

So, the probability of getting a six is $$P(\textrm{pick false die}) + P(\textrm{pick true die})\cdot P(\textrm{roll 6}) = \frac13 + \frac23\cdot\frac16 = \frac13+\frac19 = \color{red}{\frac49}$$

So, our answer is $$\bigg(\frac49\bigg)^4 = \bigg(\frac23\bigg)^8 \sim\color{red}{0.039}$$